# IE8 background-size workaround

Tags: internet-explorer, css, retina-display

I am trying to fix a display issue that involves the background-size CSS3 property in IE8 and below. In order optimize my logo for retina displays, I implemented the following code:

```
.logo {
background: url('../img/logo_sm.png') no-repeat scroll transparent;
text-indent: -999em;
transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
margin: 0;
width: 141px;
height: 32px;
background-size: 141px 32px;
display: inline-block;
```

Then I added these lines to make IE8 resize the logo properly (since it does not respect background-size)

```
/* Make IE8 cooperate */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../img/logo_sm.png', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../img/logo_sm.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

The problem is now in all versions of IE, the original background image displays behind the new, properly resized image coming from those filters.

How can I set this up so IE8 and below ignores the original background property and only renders one image? I would like to do this without the need for a separate IE only stylesheet if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, at work we no longer support less than IE7.
1) Override IE7
2) Override IE8 & IE9
3) Add it back for IE9

```
*selector {background:none;} /* IE7 */
selector {background:none\9;} /* IE9, IE8 */
:root selector {background: url('../img/logo_sm.png') no-repeat scroll transparent\9;} /* IE9 */
```